# View local Azure Webjobs SDK dashboard for debugging WebJobs SDK console process

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have a VS 2013 RC 4 Azure Webjobs project that I'm currently debugging.
The project is a console project and has a function that uses a `QueueTrigger` attribute.

I get the following errors in the console output when I run the job and insert a message to the `template-mail-requests` Azure queue.

```
MassMailer.Functions.ProcessQueueMessage
Job host started
Executing: 'Functions.ProcessQueueMessage' because New queue message detected on 'template-mail-requests'.
  Function had errors. See Azure WebJobs SDK dashboard for details. Instance id is a29182d2-42da-46b9-9443-6054ab98dfc8
```

The function signature is

`public static async Task ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("template-mail-requests")] TemplateMailRequest mailRequest, string id, int dequeueCount, TextWriter log)`

How can i  view the Azure webjobs SDK dashboard for a locally running WebJobs SDK project to debug why I'm getting this error (its likely Json Deserialization but I need to know more about which element is causing the issue)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the Dashboard to run locally you can sync the [dashboard sources from GitHub](https://github.com/azure/azure-webjobs-sdk) and add your Storage connectionstring and run the dashboard locally.

Comment: This worked! I added instructions on turning off strong name verification as the assemblies are partially signed and fail strong name verification.

Answer (score 0):

Are you strictly only running these locally, or do you also have a WebApp you're deploying them to? If the latter, assuming you've configured your WebApp to use the same storage connection strings, you can view the dashboard as you normally would and your local function executions will show up. I.e., if you have a WebApp "myapp" and you've configured the storage settings, you can navigate to see your functions here: https://myapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/#/functions.

Comment: I wanted to debug the job before I published it, so this was strictly local.